# What's the difference between path and url in react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

```
const { path, url } = useRouteMatch()
```

What's the difference between these two destructured properties returned from the hook? I log them but they seem same.

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/match This works for you ?

Comment: @burrito Thanks but it's a bit abstract. It would be great if I see an example.

Comment: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/what-is-the-difference-between-path-and-url-in-match-prop-of-reactrouter-route-component-react-router-basics There is an example here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While surfing through the source code of `react-router`, I found this:

*// The `path` lets us build  paths that are

// relative to the parent route, while the `url` lets

// us build relative links.*

```js
let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
```

[read `useRouteMatch()` source code on github](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/13fa63ed1b0d5dfb647a03319e78251413df0105/packages/react-router/modules/hooks.js#L44)

[`useRouteMatch()` example](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/13fa63ed1b0d5dfb647a03319e78251413df0105/packages/react-router-dom/examples/Nesting.js#L60)

Comment: I searched a bit more too and I found that the path is dynamic and it's the path given <Route path={path}> component while url is the exact url on the website. Path allows you to use parameters in nested Routes. If the path is users/:id you can reach the id using useParams() hook but if it's url, it will be only users/123 and since there is no parameter you can't reach the id. I guess this is the main difference between them.

Comment: this https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting doc indecate differently about the url. i still did not understand it

Comment: i think url includes the parents of the parents. e.g. url = /first/second vs path = /second when we are at first/second/<some-id>